# make bash exit if declare statement fails

Tags: bash, bash-expansion

***tl;dr*** I want bash to automatically exit after `declare var=$(false)`.

My bash scripts use `set -e` (or `set errexit`).  However, when using `declare` variable declaration idiom, the `declare` appears to "block" returning the return code from a shell substitution.

```
$ var=$(false)
$ echo $?
1

$ declare var=$(false)
$ echo $?
0
```

Therefore, bash will not exit due to the error.  I know I could test `var` but that is too cumbersome after every `declare` statement.

**How to automatically exit bash after a failure during `declare`?**

*Edit*: To clarify, I am looking for an Answer that 1) works for possibly locally scoped variables, and 2) works for possibly readonly variables, and 3) requires only one statement.

Comment: You should ask a different Q instead of changing its scope. You want it read-only, locally scoped *and* in one statement? Take this: `declare -r $(trap "kill $$" ERR; false)`. Now, where's my prize money?

Comment: @mosvy your code `declare -r $(trap "kill $$" ERR; false)` does not set a variable.

Comment: sorry, `declare -r var=$(trap "kill $$" ERR; false)`

Comment: Try using [shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), an amazing lint tool for shell scripts, with an editor plugin - this specifically warns that this sort of code masks the exit status, as well as highlighting many other issues with shell scripts such as vars that are set and never used (probably typos).

Answer (score 6):

Using `set -e` will *not* work as intended with the code you have. The reason being for the `errexit` to trigger the command has to return a non-zero exit code, but with

```
declare var=$(false)
```

though the assignment of `false` and the result of the `$(..)` causes a non-zero exit code, using `declare` obfuscates this error code and since the command by itself ran without any problem assigning a value to variable `var`, the `delcare` built-in sets the exit code to `0` which causes your error trap not to fire.

One way to solve the problem would be to separate the `declare` initialization and the value assignment

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
declare var
var=$(false)
```

Not only `declare` other built-ins like `export` and`local` also obscure the exit code when used in cases like above. See a case of using `local` in a function

```
set -e
f() { local var=$(false); }
f
```

As with the above case of `declare`, here in the function `local` obscures the exit code set from `$(..)`. You need to separate the initialization and assignment to `var` to make it working.

[BashFAQ/105 - Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) explains in detail about the pitfalls of using `set -e` and also the recommended error handling mechanisms.

Comment: Also see [this amazing table](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/), linked from the BashFAQ.

Comment: How would I `declare -r` something in this case?  I know the answer is to use three statements (`declare var; var=... ; declare -r var;`).  But that is obnoxiously verbose.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979: If you are setting a constant value which is not expected to change ( not exit codes ), you can do this in one line `declare -r var='value'`

Comment: Or use the `readonly` built-in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/readonly.html with which you can set a value something as `var=value` and make it read-only as `readonly var`

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979: Does that answer your question now?

Comment: > "Or use the readonly built-in"
Using `readonly` instead of `declare -r` still results in three statements to simply set a variable while using automatic error checking.  `declare var; var=...; readonly var;`.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979: You don't need the `declare var` in that case. Just the other two is sufficient

Comment: > "u don't need the declare var in that case."
Without `declare`, variables are automatically global.  Often I do not want that.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Actually I consider `declare X=$(false) && echo wrong` outputting `wrong` to be a BASH bug.

Answer (score 2):

You must separate the error on the right hand side of an assignement form the command used. If you want a "one line solution" for the declare command, you can use:

```
value=$(false); declare -r var="$value"
```

If you do not want to use a new var, you can use builtin ephemeral vars like either `$REPLY` (used by read) or `$_` (the last argument of a previous command line).

Using `$REPLY` might be as simple as:

```
REPLY=$(false); declare -r var="$REPLY"
```

Using `$_` may become complex or convoluted.

For me: Using `set -e` has proven to be more of a problem than a solution. Avoid it.